# How to provide unique auth in Gatling to each virtual user (java)?

Tags: java, performance, testing, gatling

I am trying to get a simulation going where each virtual user in Gatling has a unique login/auth and does a bunch of actions that I have recorded and coded up. But I'm struggling to setup the authorization properly. Here's my code

```
public class SampleSimulation extends Simulation {
  static Random rand = new Random();
  HttpProtocolBuilder httpProtocol = http
      .baseUrl("http://base-url.com") // Here is the root for all relative URLs
      .acceptHeader("text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8") // Here are the common headers
      .acceptEncodingHeader("gzip, deflate")
      .acceptLanguageHeader("en-US,en;q=0.5")
      .userAgentHeader("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0");
      // .basicAuth("username", "password");
static ActionBuilder addAuthentication(String name){
    String username = "username"; // generate random username from valid ones
    String pw = "password";  // generate random password that's valid for username
    http.basicAuth(username, pw);
    return http(name).get("/rest/activity/me");
  }
static ActionBuilder getMe(String name){
    return http(name)
        .get("/rest/activity/me");
  }

...

 ScenarioBuilder scn = scenario("name")
                        .feed(Utils.getItemIdFeeder())
                        .exec(addAuthentication("n"))
                        .exec(getMe("n")).pause(Duration.ofMillis(300),Duration.ofMillis(750))
                        .exec(postUpdateLocale("n")).pause(Duration.ofMillis(0),Duration.ofMillis(4))
                        .exec(getBalance("n")).pause(Duration.ofMillis(500), Duration.ofMillis(2000))
                        .exec(getMe("n")).pause(Duration.ofMillis(0), Duration.ofMillis(15))
                        .exec(getInventory("n")).pause(Duration.ofMillis(100), Duration.ofMillis(250))
                       );

 {
    setUp(scn.injectOpen(nothingFor(4), // 1
              atOnceUsers(10), // 2
              rampUsers(10).during(5)) //, // 3
          .protocols(httpProtocol));
 }
}
```

So when I provide username and password in the static declaration (the .basicAuth line I have commented out) it works. However each virtual user created by gatling is the same user as far as the server is concerned. If I run the code that I have added here, I get http 401s for all of my requests, which is unauthorized.

Can anyone please explain to me what I'm doing wrong, what is the proper way of doing credentials in Gatling is? Note that I'm already using a feeder for itemIds.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
http.basicAuth(username, pw);
return http(name).get("/rest/activity/me");
```

This does absolutely nothing as HttpProtocolBuilder is [immutable](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/concepts/#immutability).

I advice you invest some time to read the documentation and the [Gatling Academy](https://gatling.io/academy/), you'll ultimately save a lot of time.

If you check `basicAuth`'s [documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/http/protocol/#authorization), you can see that it can also take Gatling EL expressions, so you could do something like:

1. `.basicAuth("#{username}", "#{password}")`
2. inject for each virtual user the desired key-value pairs, eg with a [feeder](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/session/feeder/) or an [exec block with a function](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/scenario/#exec)